# How to move or copy a figure with .png extension from one folder to other folder?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have save a figure in folder Dist with .png extension. Now in a for loop I want to implement a condition that if i<3 move or copy a certain figure from one folder to other. How can I do that in python?

Answer (score 0):

Here is two methods of how you can copy a file to another folder:

For example if we have this tree directory:

```
.
├── destination  # destination directory
├── moving.py    # script that copies files
└── test.png     # file to be copied
```

**moving.py:**

```
import os
import shutil


# Method 1
def copy_file(filename: str, destination: str):
    """Copy file to destination using shutil package
       :param: filename is the file name path
       :param: destination is the destination path
    """
    shutil.copy(filename, destination)


# Method 2
def copy_file2(filename: str, destination: str):
    """Copy file to destination"""
    data = b''
    # Read the file in binary mode
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        data = f.read()
    # Write the file in binary mode
    with open(os.path.join(destination, filename), 'wb') as f:
        f.write(data)


# Example
filename = 'test.png'
destination = 'destination'
copy_file(filename, destination)
# copy_file2(filename, destination)
```

Both methods will copy the file to the new destination path and it'll keep the original name of the copied file.

Bonus: For more informations about `shutil.copy()` function i recommend you reading the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy)